# upgrading app in the android market (google)

Tags: android, google-play

I do this process almost every day for other applications. But now I'm having trouble with an specific one. After I upload it, I click on activate (which works perfect), but when I go back to the market or refresh the old app shows as active and the new one still have the button of "activate"; i activate it again and the story repeats itself.

Answer (score 3):

Enable these two options on `Consent`

```
This application meets Android Content Guidelines

I acknowledge that my software application may be subject to United States export laws, regardless of my location or nationality. I agree that I have complied with all such laws, including any requirements for software with encryption functions. I hereby certify that my application is authorized for export from the United States under these laws. [Learn More]
```

and then activate new version apk. Later click on save and then click on home link.

Comment: To those who may be wondering where this option is at, it's inside the  Pricing & Distribution, at the end of the page (Consent)

Answer (score 0):

Deactivate previous version and activate current one.

Answer (score 0):

Try use latest Google Chrome and deactivate and activate the current APK again.